# How do I change my Youtube nickname from "Firstname Lastname" to "Nickname" or just "Firstname"

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management, youtube-channel, google-account-profile

I'm encountering a small but rather frustrating stupid problem that's driving me mad.

At some point Google insisted on me specifying a first and last name. I entered "Stromboli" for both. Since then, my nickname appears as "Stromboli Stromboli" (i.e. twice).

I have changed my nickname, I have removed the last name, but no matter what I try... It seems to looks OK in all profile settings but when I actually place a comment anywhere on Youtube, it *still* appears as "Stromboli Stromboli".

Here's some screenshots of what I tried, with the current settings.

• Youtube top right profile popup:

[image: screenshot]

• Youtube settings:

[image: screenshot]

• When I click Edit on Google:

[image: screenshot]

• The dropdown options for "Display my name as" are:

[image: screenshot]

• Back in in my Google profile:

[image: screenshot]

• Clicking the top right popup:

[image: screenshot]

• When I click on "My Account", I get to Personal info in Google:

[image: screenshot]

• Top right google account popup:

[image: screenshot]

• And even my Gmail settings:

[image: screenshot]

• However... When I place a comment on a video, or when I enter the chat in a Live stream:

[image: screenshot]

Would anyone know how I can get Youtube to just show my name as "Stromboli" (once, not twice) when I place comments on videos or streams??

Note: instead of using a first and/or last name, I also see a lot of Youtube comments using only a custom nickname. So I know it's possible. That'd be also great for me, is there a way I can specify to just use a nickname on Youtube?

Comment: Check and see what your Google+ profile says.  I've (anecdotally) found that overriding names in some weird places.

Comment: Is Google+ something else than [this](https://i.imgur.com/LralGE2.jpg) and [this](https://i.imgur.com/SE3561T.jpg) step from above?

Comment: What happens if you put a single dot as your surname? That used to be the workaround from back in the day when last names were required, YouTube doesn't display the dot.

Comment: @Stromboli Yeah, it's their "social networking" site.  If you google your username and you still have a G+ profile out there, it will come up

Comment: @LeoWattenberg That worked like a charm. I've added that as the solution, all credit to you! For some reason I cannot up +1 your comment, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Wattenberg's comment: the solution is to simply change my last name into . (a dot)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a comment on another question when I saw it in review.